# Pick the latest file based on timestamp provided in the filename

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have to pick the files in order(first file first) from say a folder (C:\Users) and file name has the timestamp in it. 
For example below are my files in C:\Users\ and the time stamp is after the first underscore i.e. 20170126102806 in the first file below. I have to loop through files and pick the first file and so on. so out of 5 files below,20170123-000011_20170126101823_AAA is the first file. How do I do this in SSIS?

```
1.20170123-000011_20170126102806_AAA
2.20170123-000011_20170126103251_AAA
3.20170123-000011_20170126101823_AAA
4.20170123-000011_20170126103305_AAA
5.20170123-000011_20170126102641_AAA
```

Comment: To confirm, you want to process all files in a certain order, correct? Could you show the files in the order that you want to process them?

Answer (score 0):

You can act in two ways:

- use the foreach loop container to get the list of files, and then populate a database table.

  Then, outside the foreach loop, use an Execute SQL to select from that table using an appropriate ORDER BY. 
  Load an object variable with the result set. Then use a second foreach loop to step through the variable object and collect files.
- use a Script Task to retrieve the contents of the folder (the list of files) and sort files then load an object variable with the dataset. Then use a foreach loop to step through the variable object to collect files.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a script task in a For Each Loop. Use the filename returned as the source to load each time.

`using System.IO;`

```
public void Main()
{
string filePath = "D:\\Temp";
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
var files = dir.GetFiles("*_AAA");//Or from a variable
DateTime fileCreateDate1 = File.GetCreationTime(filePath + "\\" + files[0]);
        if (files.Length >= 2)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                DateTime fileCreateDate2 = File.GetCreationTime(filePath+ "\\" + files[i]);

                if (fileCreateDate1 < fileCreateDate2)
                {
                    fileCreateDate1 = fileCreateDate2; 
                }
            }   
        }

        Dts.Variables["User::FileToLoad"].Value = fileCreateDate1;
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

You will have to remove the file after it was loaded or else it will be loaded each time as it is the oldest or latest file.
There might be a bug or so, but have similar code that works. Just iron it out if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/76701192/11262633, you can use a Foreach Loop Container.  This is similar to `elax`'s suugestion, but does not require populating a  database table and doing a subsequent select.